# Where $\log(1+z^2)$ is complex differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

Where $\log(1+z^2)$ is complex differentiable?

I use the fact, that logarithm of $1+z$ is equal to its Taylor series expansion whenever $|z| \le 1$ and $z\ne -1$.

So the answer is that $\log(1+z^2)$ is complex differentaible when $|z|\le1$ and $z\ne i, z\ne-i$.

Is that correct?

I'm not sure if that is enough.

Comment: You need to establish a single valued analytic branch.  If we wind around, $z=\pm i$, is $f$ single valued still? We can do this three waays 1 around $i$ alone, 2 around $-i$ alone and 3 around both.

Comment: we take $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{x< 0\}$

Comment: I know what you mean. $\log$ from first post is the main branch of logarithm (we cut the negative x axis and 0 from the domain).

Comment: What happens when you wind around the branch points of $z=\pm i$? Is it single or multivalued?

Comment: I don't get it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z + i = r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $z - i = r_2e^{i\theta_2}$. Now
$$
\log(z^2+1) = \log[(z - i)(z + i)] = \log(r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}) = \log\lvert r_1r_2\rvert + i[\theta_1 + \theta_2]
$$
If we go $2\pi$ around $z + i$, then we have $r_1e^{i(\theta_1 + 2\pi)}$ which leads to
$$
\log(z^2+1) = \log[(z - i)(z + i)] = \log(r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_1 + 2\pi + \theta_2)}) = \log\lvert r_1r_2\rvert + i[\theta_1 + \theta_2] + 2\pi i
$$
We change by $2\pi$ so it isn't single valued. Same occurs if we go around $z = -i$. If we encircle both, we change by $4\pi i$. Additionally, $z=\infty$ is a branch point. To stop the encircling of the branch points we draw branch cuts to make the $f(z)$ analytic. That is, the branch cuts of $(-\infty, -i]\cup [i, \infty)$ will suffice. To prove that $z=\infty$ is a branch point, let $z = 1/\zeta$. Then $f(z) = \log\bigl(\frac{1 + \zeta^2}{\zeta^2}\bigr) = \log(1 + \zeta^2) - 2\log(\zeta)$ so $\zeta = 0$ is branch point then $z = \infty$ is one.

So $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C} - (-\infty, -i]\cup [i, \infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

We first find the inverse image of the negative real axis (and $0$) for $g(z)=1+z^2$.This is found to be the part of the imaginary axis with modulus $\geq 1$. $f(z)=log (1+z^2)$ is defined outside this set and differentiable there by the chain rule giving $f'(z)=\frac{2z}{1+z^2} $.

Comment: what do you mean "differentiable by chain rule"?

Comment: f is composition of two functions log and g right?Then what is the formula for f'(z)?

Comment: Ah i know. So we are using fact that both that functions are C differentiable yes

Comment: @toimek343 yes , they are complex diff. in their domain of definition and we use that fact...